# Only read lines of (very big) file equal to a specific value (using R)

Tags: r

I have a file with 54 million lines and it is to big to read the whole file, it doesnt fit in memory. Using R, I want to extract som 100 000 lines from the file where the content of one of the columns is equal to a certain number. Does anyone know if this is possible without having to read the entire file? All columns contains integers, if that makes any difference.

The contents of the file looks like:

```
Date,ProductId,Stock,Price
199501,1,271,5
199501,2,145,50
199501,3,16,42
199501,4,32,45
199501,5,96,62
```

Comment: One option could also be using `scan`, depending on your definition of "very big".

Comment: Very big in this case is 2 GB, I tried to use scan to read the whole file but ran out of memory. If it is possible to use scan to only read part of the file, depending on column values, that might be an alternative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Details of your question are unclear, but in many cases the detour via sqldf is the fastest solution if the file otherwise is well structured.

http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_13._read.csv.sql_and_read.csv2.sql

If this does not help, you should give more details by posting a short sample of 10 lines including simple code that does what you want, even if it is slow. Someone will jump in and optimize it, but this is not possible without sample data.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great! I added a sample of the file to the original question in case it helps someone else. I could find the rows i needed by using:    read.csv.sql('file.txt',sep=',',sql='select * from file where Date=199501')